# Trying to write a script to get my twitter timeline, cannot get return information

Tags: twitter-oauth, timeline

I’m trying to write a twitter program to get my tinme line. I’m using    Abraham
Williams authentication code.   I cannot figure out how to pharse the return value.  I think it is return a stdClass, which I’m confused about how it works.  I can display the objects values by print_r.  I was able to see what the xml and json return values would be at http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline.

code

```
// Read in our saved access token/secret
$accessToken = file_get_contents("access_token");
$accessTokenSecret = file_get_contents("access_token_secret");
// Create our twitter API object
require_once("twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php");
$oauth = new TwitterOAuth('mykey', 'secret key', $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);
// Send an API request to verify credentials
$credentials = $oauth->get("account/verify_credentials");
echo "Connected as @" . $credentials->screen_name;
// Post our new "hello world" status

$home_timeline = $oauth->get('statuses/home_timeline',array('count' => 40));  
print_r($home_timeline);
// how do i get the information out of home_timeline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GET statues/home_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline) returns an array of statues. You can either access them directly like `$home_timeline[0]->text` or write a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
foreach ($home_timeline as $status) {
  echo "Tweet: $status->text<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi,It worcked, I', assuming $home_timeline is an array of objects? The program did display all the tweets on my timeline, but is there a way to get the icon url that goes with each tweet?

Comment: Yes, `$home_timeline` is an array of status objects. Inside of each status object is a `user` object. To get a users profile image you would use `$status->user->profile_image_url`.